# function over list with condition

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

For a fake function like:

```
fun[x_] := x^0/x!;
```

and list:

```
list={0,0,0.1,0.2,0.9,0.8,0,0};
```

It will get error in this way cause the 0^0 is indeterminate:

```
fun[list]
```

In that case,I want to just leave the 0 element in the list as it is and only calculate the element that larger than 0. Are there some easy and fast way to implement this?

Comment: `fun[x_?Positive] := x^0/x!;fun[0]=0;`

Comment: fun[x_] := x^0/x! /; x > 0
fun[0] = 0;
fun /@ list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a special case for the $0$ input.

```
ClearAll[fun]
fun[0] = 0
fun[x_] := x^0/x!
SetAttributes[fun, Listable]

fun[list]

(* Out: {0, 0, 1.05114, 1.08912, 1.03975, 1.07367, 0, 0} *)
```

---

Notice that you *can* use your original function on a list directly (i.e. `fun[list]` instead of *mapping it* over a list as  in `fun /@ list`), because you take advantage of the `Listable` attributes of the operations used in your function.

If you define the special case for $0$ input, however, it is easiest to make your function explicitly `Listable` so that it itself automatically threads over lists and the $0$ special case fires appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!